# Does System.IO.File.Move() copy all the bytes to destination?

Tags: c#, system.io.file

Does `System.IO.File.Move()` method actually copy all the bytes to destination and then deletes the file from source or it's only changes the file pointer (physical address) so now file appears to be in different location?

**Update 1**
I am trying to move it on the same volume. for example from `D:\SourceDir\sourcefile.pdf` to `D:\DestinationDir\destinationfile.pdf`

Comment: it copies the bytes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That depends on whether the source and destination reside on the same disk volume.

Comment: @Nkosi .... that just confirms it copies the bytes if the move is across disk volumes, it says nothing about the same volume.

Comment: @Nkosi Could you be more specific... I don't see anything in the linked document to support your claim.

Comment: Check source code : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,47c527ad52ea10da

Comment: @Nkosi .... and?  That tells me it calls the Win32 MoveFile function.  Which I believe renames if it can.

Comment: See my update 1. I am trying to move on same volume

Answer (score 2):

internally it calls MoveFile - see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs,c4000fcf90b3c6db

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx

And the answer is - it depends, if it can it renames the file, otherwise it copies it